# What are .o.ur-safe files generated by Linux kernel module build?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module, kbuild

What is the purpose of `*.o.ur-safe` files generated when building a kernel module? I couldn't find a reference to this extension in the kernel source, or anywhere else.

Here's the (fairly standard) Makefile:

```make
obj-m += module.o

module-y := main.o other.o

KDIR ?= "/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build"

all:
    make -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) clean
```

other.o.ur-safe is generated on running `make`. Here are the contents of other.o.ur-safe:

```
/home/user/module/other.o-.text-17
/home/user/module/other.o-.text-27
/home/user/module/other.o-.text-32
/home/user/module/other.o-.text-42
```

Observations:

- `make clean` does not delete this file.
- A corresponding `.o.ur-safe` file isn't generated for main.o.
- This file isn't generated on Ubuntu 16.04.7 with Linux 4.19.99, but it is generated by Ubuntu 16.04.7 with Linux 4.4.0-186-generic. The former (machine A) is a custom Ubuntu installation, but the latter (machine B) is just a stock Ubuntu image.
- This file is not generated by (B) when I use a 4.4.186 kernel source tree as KDIR.